# Stuck on Cutscene in Dishonored - What Can I Do?

Tags: pc, dishonored, linux, wine

**My Problem**

So, today I got the game Dishonored on Steam and I've been trying it out. Unfortunately, I can't get past the first five minutes or so of the game because I get stuck on the conversation with the little girl Emily. After she's done talking, she just kind of stops, stands still and stares at me. Forever.

I can look around and see other people moving in the vicinity, and I can open the menu. However, If I try to load any games or go back to the main menu or anything, it loads for an indefinitely long time. I also get indefinitely long loads when trying to play things from the "Missions" section. These last 15+ minutes - at that point I figured they weren't going anywhere, considering that loading the actual game only takes a few seconds.

The prior cutscene with the boat works fine.

**Unusual Circumstances/Potential Causes**

I'm running this on Linux (specifically Fedora 20) with Wine (specifically version 1.7.8). I don't *think* the problem is with Wine; as I'm running both Steam and Dishonored in terminals I'm not getting any error messages or warnings at the point I get stuck. It's not really characteristic of most of the Wine issues I've had in any case. It's also very uncharacteristic of a graphics issue (I am using the open source drivers though which have only recently started working for me for games). Additionally, the game is rated very highly for Wine compatibility and no-one mentions similar issues, [you can see the appdb page here](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=26804&iTestingId=74605). Both are vague possibilities, though.

**What I've Discovered**

I've found instances of similar problems, most notably [this YouTube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k3zsLtqhfOY). I've found comments about the same issue to the effect it goes away when you leave the area. However, I am obviously not capable of blinking around as the game has just started.

I am getting pretty frustrated with this as I've spent several hours in the game and researching the issue without ever progressing beyond the first five minutes. What, if anything, can be done about this? Thank you for any assistance.

**EDIT**: After resetting basically everything (new Wineprefix, new Steam install, new download and install of Dishonored) I got it to work...for a few hours. Most of the original issues returned after restarting the game, though I haven't tested the cutscene itself since I'm past that point now. I will add the additional comment that Steam does part of the "first time set up" every time I start the game, reinstalling DirectX and the VCRUN redistributable.

Comment: You can fix the reinstalling of dx and vcredist by deleting installscript.vdf or making it empty and setting it to read only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seem to have found a solution. I renamed the Dishonored/Binaries/Redist folder (where I assume the repeated startup reinstalls were going).

I also disabled the reinstalls (I don't know 100% for sure if this was actually a factor as it didn't work without renaming the folder and I didn't test renaming the folder without disabling the reinstalls) as Assylum recommended, with some additions:

- Deleting the installscript.vdf file didn't work as a new one was just generated, so I emptied it and changed permissions to read only
- Changing the permissions alone wasn't sufficient to fix it (on Linux, might work on Windows); I also changed the owner of the file to root

For anyone who should happen on this and need a little help finding the necessary directory and file, the Redists directory is located in

```
Program Files/Steam/SteamApps/common/Dishonored/Binaries/
```

and the installscript.vdf file is located in

```
Program Files/Steam/SteamApps/common/Dishonored/
```

This all fixed the following issues:

- Game getting stuck in cutscene mode after a certain cutscene (not all cutscenes, but at least one and maybe more)
- No audio after the startup logos
- Indefinite but very long (maybe infinite) loading times exiting the game and trying to load DLC missions
- Repeated "first run" software installation on starting the game

Also keep in mind these unusual circumstances:

- I'm using Linux and Wine to run the game, so this could have partially caused the issue
- I'm not using Radeon's proprietary graphics drivers, which also impacts some games (admittedly not usually in this way)

That's not to say this necessarily couldn't fix a similar issue on Windows or that it automatically would work on a similar Wine issue, of course.

Comment: I just wanted to confirm that deleting the content of installscritp.vdf fixed the cutscene bug for me (Windows 10).